# How to install DirectPlay on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I don't know if this is proper place to ask, so sorry if it is not.

I have a problem with enabling/installing DirectPlay. Most people for enabling this need to just go to 'Turn Windows features on or off' then 'Legacy Components' and there it is.

My problem is that I don't have 'Legacy Components' on tree there. Its old DX component afaik, and I have Windows 7 so I have already newer version of DX than one with DirectPlay and old DX won't install. I couldn't found much informations about that because most people just enabling it from "Legacy Components".

I have Windows 7 Home edition, friend with Win7 Pro have this option so maybe thats problem, but still what can I do in this situation? I am clueless atm.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a K/N version of Windows 7 Home?

Comment: As far as I remember its not K/N

Comment: "As far as I remember" - Can you verify if that is the case?  "old DX won't install."  - Can you explain this comment?

Comment: Ok sorry for this, How can I exactly check my Win7 version?

Also about DX I meant that older versions of DirectX with DirectPlay do not install, because I have already newer DirectX version.

Comment: "How can I exactly check my Win7 version?" Properties on "Computer" will display the requested information.  As for "older versions of DirectX" you don't specific which version(s) you have attempted.  Anything before DX 9 wouldn't even be compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, I thought I could get more specific informations about my Win7, here are more specific from dxdiag:
Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_ldr.170810-1615)

Unless you meant other check?

And about DirectX I have tried version before 9 and probably 9.0c (said here the current is newer and did nothing).

Comment: You can installed DX9c independently of the version of DX installed by default on Windows 7.  So if you are being told DX9c is already installed it likely is.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 do ship *already* with DirectPlay out of the box (minus some Voice and NAT features that [have been](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667682/5994170) uprooted for good in Vista). You don't even need DXSETUP, since it is for something else [completely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33251171/5994170).

It was only [starting](https://web.archive.org/web/20130812043602/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn323745(v=vs.85).aspx) with Windows 8.1 that it became optional and on demand.